# JFrame component must have a valid peer

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, awt

I'm trying to make my application go fullscreen whenever you press F11. To do this I create a new window and give it the same canvas used by the previous window.

```
public void setFullscreen(boolean bool) {
    fullscreen = bool;
    jf.dispose();
    jf = createFrame();
}

public JFrame createFrame() {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame(title);
    
    jf.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    jf.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    jf.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    if(fullscreen) {
        jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        jf.setUndecorated(true);
    }
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setResizable(false);
    jf.add(canvas);
    jf.pack();
    jf.requestFocus();
    jf.setIconImage(img);
            
    return jf;

}
```

If I render the window now, I randomly get the error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer". This is my render for my canvas.

public void render() {

```
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    
    if(bs == null) {    
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    
    //Render all the stuff on screen here
            
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();  
    
}
```

To avoid this, I made my window only render its canvas when the frame is valid using the isValid() method.

```
public void render() {
    if(jf.isValid())
        canvas.render();
}
```

This, however, does not solve it. Why do I still get the error?

NOTE: I know that I am mixing awt and swing components (recently learned it's a bad idea), but switching from JFrame to a normal Frame doesn't solve it either.

Comment: First, stop rendering.  Once you've created and made the window visible, use something like `EventQueue.invokeLater` to start rendering again

Comment: However, I don't know why you need to switch frames :/

Comment: @MadProgrammer I switched frames as I was told in a tutorial that you had to do that if you are using bufferstrategy. However, I don't know how true that is, since I get the exact  same problem if I just try to change the dimension of the current frame.

Comment: In this case using `Frame` or `JFrame` is irrelevant, if all you using is `Canvas`, just don't add anything to it.  The question I was asking is why you'd need to create a new frame.  Just change extended state

Comment: As mentioned, I was told that creating a new frame would help, but it still had the exact same problem as just changing the extended state.